# Binding @objc var [Double] array, setter never fired

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have a NSTableView, content bind to [Double] array in file's owner `currentStaleValues`:

```
@objc var currentStyleValues: [Double] {
    get {
        print ("getting currentStyleValues")
        guard let values = sliders.currentStyle?.egdesValues else {return []}
        return values
    }
    set {
        print ("setting currentStyleValues", newValue )
        guard let style = sliders.currentStyle else {return}
        print (newValue)
        style.egdesValues = newValue.map {$0.doubleValue}
    }
}
```

It looks simple enough, but as getter works perfect and I can see right values in NSTableView, setter is never fired.
Is some simple way to fire setter from NSTableView after cell editing end? Or I have to add NSArrayController, build class with `.values`, spend much more time on code?

Comment: A KVO compliant property must be marked as `dynamic`

Comment: Like this?:  @objc dynamic var currentStyleValues: [Double]? It doesn't work too.

Comment: If you are using Xcode, it gives message that "Value of type 'Double' has no member 'doubleValue'."

Comment: It never goes to this line. Never prints`setting currentStyleValues`. It's here because I copy/paste code and earlier I tried `[NSNumber]` with a same result.